# MyPy gives false alarm on `mutagen.id3.PictureType`

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting, mutagen

I am writing some Python code (to manipulate audio metadata) using [mutagen](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/tree/main) library.  The library does not have type hints, however I have added type hints to my routines.  In particular, I have a function with the following signature:

```py
from mutagen import id3

def fun(arg1: str, arg2: id3.PictureType = id3.PictureType.ARTIST):
    # the body of the function
```

But, MyPy complains about the default argument assignment:

```
error: Incompatible default for argument "arg2" (default has type "int", argument has type "PictureType")
```

I am confused and cannot figure out why this is happening.  I checked that:

```
>>> isinstance(id3.PictureType.ARTIST, id3.PictureType)
True
>>> isinstance(id3.PictureType.ARTIST, int)
True
>>> issubclass(id3.PictureType.ARTIST.__class__, int)
True
>>> inspect.getmro(id3.PictureType.ARTIST.__class__)
(mutagen.id3._specs.PictureType, int, object)
```

So, it looks like the type hierarchy is correct (`id3.PictureType.ARTIST` should be an instance of `id3.PictureType` which, itself is a subclass of `int`).  Yet, MyPy is assuming `id3.PictureType.ARTIST` is of type `int`, why?

Could that be related to the "particular" way mutagen author's implement `id3.PictureType` as an enum (see [here](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/blob/f95d3ae19e25e3f0a91061566551843d799317c5/mutagen/id3/_specs.py#L17) and [here](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/blob/f95d3ae19e25e3f0a91061566551843d799317c5/mutagen/_util.py#L329))? And if so, is there a way to fix this (without re-implementing `PictureType` as a proper [Python enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html))?

Comment: enums-values are magic, as even int-enums are themselves not `int`; they just pose and act like `int`; they retain a link back to their class, so that `Foo.A != Bar.B` even if both these values are `5` (or whatever). You can use `id3.PictureType.ARTIST.value` to make mypy happy.

Comment: @user2722968 `id3.PictureType.ARTIST` has no attribute `value`.  I think in this particular case `id3.PictureType` is even a more convoluted enum (it has NOT been implemented using standard Python Enums).

Comment: [enums are implemented as a special mypy plugin](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/plugins/enums.py), because they can't be described with type annotations in the standard typing system. `id3.PictureType = id3.PictureType.ARTIST` would only pass type checking if `id3.PictureType` inherits from a `enum.Enum` class (or has `enum.EnumType` as the metaclass). `id3` doesn't implement it this way (opting for an [untyped decorator `@enum` which is not from the standard library](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/blob/f95d3ae19e25e3f0a91061566551843d799317c5/mutagen/_util.py#L329)).

Comment: yeah, there's no way that `enum` decorator is going to be understood by `mypy`, it dynamically creates a new class and does a bunch of other stuff. I don't understand the lengths people go to simply not use the standard library `enum.Enum` and just use `my_enum.value`

Comment: Custom enums were probably written before Python supported enums (`enum.Enum` is new in version 3.4), and the older the software the more Hyrun's Law holds. To make this custom `@enum` by `id3` work, you'll have to (1) [add a `py.typed` file](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#packaging-type-information) and (2) write a mypy plugin which transforms the AST of `@enum`-decorated classes into something inheriting e.g. `enum.Enum`, done before semantic analysis (e.g. during the [`get_additional_deps` method](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html#current-list-of-plugin-hooks)).